# C++ Linux - backgrounded process stop at keyboard press key

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I have an app that prints to terminal outputs.
When put it in background (with '&'), and press any key, e.g. press Enter 
to redisplay the prompt (just to check that I'm still in bash when some output
from the background process has been displayed), the background process seems to stop spontaneously:

```
    [1] Stopped (tty output) app
```

I understood that its because process get SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU, here probably SIGTTIN, and SIGTTOU in case of printf etc.
so I have two questions:
**1.** I tried to handle it from app side, simply block SIGTTOU and SIGTTIN, it helps for this case, I can press any key in the shell, ***but*** when I execute process in foreground - of course all my keystrokes are ignored!!!
so, how to handle so it'll work in fg **and** bg ???
maybe detach process from terminal and tty, but will app still able to print to console?

**2.** In general, who have to handle these signals? app or maybe it should be handle in tty configuration. (TOSTOP?)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**1. How to handle so it'ill work in fg and bg?**

If your app only prints output to console, SIGTTIN or SIGTTOU will not be a problem.

In your case, it seems your app prints output to console and needs input from console.
If your app have to print output and have to wait input from console, you cannot run the app in bg, successfully.

**2. Who have to handle these signals?**

Generally, an app should handle theses signals. You should choose one of `SIG_DFL`(default action), `SIG_IGN`(ignore), or programmer-defined function.